# fuzzywuzzy process.extract() not returning a list

Tags: python, fuzzywuzzy

I'm relatively new to programming and while doing my university assignment, I've been running into problems with the `process.extract()` function from the `fuzzywuzzy` package.

The [documentation](https://www.kite.com/python/docs/fuzzywuzzy.process.extract) says the function should return a list, however, my code returns an object with a class type of `None`.

If I print the `process.extract(limit=1)` it returns what looks like a list:

```
[("Matching string","Fuzz Ratio", "Index")]
```

However I can't slice this object using `[]` because it is classified as `None`.

I need to be able to get the index of the matching string so either I need to find out why `process.extract()` isn't returning a list or how to get the last element out of the `None` object.

Thanks and if any clarification is required, let me know.

EDIT: Ok my bad guys I'll try to be more specific.

Minimal reproducable sample:

Note: CSV file is simply two columns of questions and answers, it's from my university so I'm not sure if I'm allowed to upload the exact file, sorry about this.

Ok so weirdly, recreating the example fixed it but I can't tell what is happening still.

The first example is taken from my original code:

```
import pandas as pd 
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process
df_chat_bot = pd.read_csv("ChatBot-short.csv")
str_user_question = input("Question: ")
test_var = print(process.extract(str_user_question, df_chat_bot["Question"], limit = 1))
print(type(test_var))
```

Output of the print(type(test_var)) line is (direct from terminal) "<class 'NoneType'>".

Then, when I went to make the reproduceable bit of code:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import pandas as pd  
test_user_question = "vsc"
df_chat_bot = pd.read_csv("ChatBot-short.csv")
temp_var = process.extract(test_user_question,df_chat_bot["Question"], limit = 1)
print(temp_var)
print(type(temp_var))
```

printing this type results in "<class 'List'>"

So what's going on here? Note that I commented out all other code from my original file so the code I pasted here is the only code being run.

Comment: Could you please [edit] to provide a [mre]?

Comment: "A class type of `None`" makes no sense - `NoneType` is at least possible, but such an object could not have a string representation other than "None".  Please show actual code/transcript that exhibits this `None` type you're talking about.

Comment: To be specific, that's a list with one element, which is a tuple of 3 elements.

Answer (score 2):

See the difference:

Your code:

```
test_var = print(process.extract(str_user_question, df_chat_bot["Question"], limit = 1))
```

Test code:

```
temp_var =       process.extract(test_user_question,df_chat_bot["Question"], limit = 1)
```

In your code, the `process.extract()` is wrapped in `print()`. The function `print()` always returns `None` and assigns that to `test_var`, which is why you're getting an error. Of course `type(None)` is `NoneType`.

If you want to both *assign* and *print* the return value of `process.extract(...)`, you have to do them in separate statements, as is done in the second example.

Comment: I see! Thank you! I hope you don't mind answering but now that I understand process.extract() better (it returns a list of 3 tuples, instead of a list of 3 elements), how can I select the tuple that I want to use? I tried temp_var[-1] but it just returns the set of 3 tuples because it is under the first element of the list. I tried to google how to do this to no success.

Thank you in advance if you do help me out :)

Comment: It looks like `process.extract()` returns a list of tuples, where each tuple represents `(value, score[, key])` for a single item in the `choices`. The output will have the same number of tuples in it as the `choices` parameter has elements, and they'll correspond. To access the value of the last match you'd do `temp_var[-1][0]`. To get the value of the single tuple with the best score, you'd do `max(temp_var, key=lambda tup:tup[1])[0]`. Note that `process.extractOne()` will essentially do the `max()` part for you, returning just one tuple rather than a list of them.